# Need help regarding angular.element

Tags: angularjs

```
angular.element('.nav > li > a:hover').css('a', '#ffffff');
```

When i passed classes or tags in angular.element this type then its not working for me. Please provide solution how to pass classes or tags in angular.element.
Even i passed class like below still its not working for me.

```
angular.element('.navbar, .navbar-static-top').css('margin-right', '-15px');
```

Please correct me where i create the mistake. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Note: Keep in mind that this function will not find elements by tag name / CSS selector. For lookups by tag name, try instead angular.element(document).find(...) or $document.find(), or use the standard DOM APIs, e.g. document.querySelectorAll()

This is what angular official documentation says. So you can not find element using `angular.element` by passing class names. So you can try `angular.element(document).find(...)` and that should do the trick. read official documentation for more info.

[Reference angular.element](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

Hope this helps :)